# How to send integer with message queue with POSIX API in linux?

Tags: linux, ipc, message-queue

I try to send integer by msg queue but the function mq_send(mq, &val , sizeof(val), 0); is working for only char type pointer so is there any way to send integer to queue with another function or same function.

Regards...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not read the **char*** in this case as the only allowed datatype.

Many *ix API use char as a generic buffer pointer.

View the interface therefore as taking a pointer to buffer and the size of the buffer.

That buffer can be anything you like, from a single int, to a struct, seralized string representation of your class, or just about anything else in memory.

```
int i;
mq_send(mq, (char *) &i, sizeof(i), 0);
```

Should work (not tested)

Good Luck