# Sending int with mq_send

Tags: queue, posix

The solution in the post below doesn't work for me. I get error message "Message too long". What can be the problem?
[How to send integer with message queue with POSIX API in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247041/how-to-send-integer-with-message-queue-with-posix-api-in-linux/13275787#13275787)

If I am correct a `pid_t` is defined as an `int`. I have done the following:

```
struct mq_attr attr;
attr.mq_flags = 0;
attr.mq_maxmsg = 1000;
attr.mq_msgsize = sizeof(pid_t);

mqd_t queue = mq_open(unique_name, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0600, &attr);

mqd_t result = mq_send(queue, &pid, sizeof(pid), 0);
```

I get the following error at compilation at the line of `mq_send`:

> "passing argument 2 of 'mq_send' from incompatible pointer type"
>   "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Comment: Did you specify a msgsize when you called `mq_open`?  You might want to post the open and send calls.

Comment: Sizeof int should be immaterial since you specify sizeof pid_t.  That looks ok to me.  Sorry, it was worth a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I never did `mq_unlink`.

Comment: if you want to avoid having to unlink, then just code `if ((queue == -1) && (errno != EEXIST))`. Of course, if the queue is already open, you might want to flush it before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to set the maximum message size and queue size with an mq_attr first. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625845/mq-receive-message-too-long?rq=1) for more detail on POSIX queues.